# img2pdf: one page of pdf with one image?

Tags: python, fpdf

The souce file is [here](https://pan.baidu.com/s/10JSwKyMOmMs_rAIt_X2Dnw).The fetch code is `sify` .It's just one jpg. If you can't download it, please contact bbliao@126.com.

However this image doesn't work with `fpdf` package, I don't know why. You can try it.

Thus I have to use the `img2pdf`. With the following code I converted this image to pdf successfully.

```
t=os.listdir()
with open('bb.pdf','wb') as f:
    f.write(img2pdf.convert(t))
```

However, when multiple images are combined into one pdf file, the `img2pdf` just combine each image  by head_to_tail. This causes every pagesize = imgaesize. Briefly, the first page of pdf is 30 cm*40 cm while the second is 20 cm*10 cm the third is 15*13...That's ugly.

I want the same pagesize(`A4` for example) and the same imgsize in every page of the pdf. One page of pdf with one image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glancing at the [documentation](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf) for img2pdf, it allows you to set the paper size by including layout details to the convert call:

```
import img2pdf
letter = (img2pdf.in_to_pt(8.5), img2pdf.in_to_pt(11))
layout = img2pdf.get_layout_fun(letter)
with open('test.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(img2pdf.convert(['image1.jpg','image2.jpg'], layout_fun=layout))
```